# Scikit Learn - K Means - Silhouette method points at 1 as the best K

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm doing a K-means task and I stumbled across some unexpected things. I'm using this [dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mice+Protein+Expression) (without the first and last four features) and I did an elbow and silhouette method for determining the best K. This is the code I use for getting the values for beforementioned methods:

```
sil = list()
wcv = {}
kmax = 10

for k in range(2, kmax+1): #kmax = 10
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k).fit(dataset_pca)
    wcv[k] = kmeans.inertia_ #use for WSS (elbow method)
    labels = kmeans.labels_
    sil.append(silhouette_score(dataset_pca, labels, metric = 'euclidean')) #use for silhouette method
```

After plotting the values from these methods, I get that 1 is the best K for my dataset. However, there are two more local maximums for silhouette at 5 and 7. My question is, should I go for 5 (or 7) or the 'research' stops here and the conclusion is that K should be 1 or with other words, this dataset is not suitable for clustering?

This is how my plot looks like and the data scattered after PCA reduced to 2 dimensions (n_components = 2).
[image: Silhouette method (left) and elbow method (right)]

[image: Scattered data]

Comment: If I am not wrong, dataset tells there are 8 classes. Your result does not have any clusters. You should increase of PCA components value.

Comment: Tried with 8 and 20 components, still getting 1 as max. Let me ask you this, I used minimax scaler in (0, 1) range and with this approach I got 2 clusters. I did a little research on the Internet and found some papers where it says that this dataset has 2 clusters. What do you think about this? @İsmailDurmaz

Comment: You can use `StandardScaler` instead of min-max. There are three categorical features that you can use `OneHotEncoder` method. I should work on the dataset to say something.

Comment: There are 64 different methods to decide on best k, silhouette and elbow only being 2 of them. It's your responsibility as a human being to decide which one is best for the problem at hand.